# Obtain Emails in PHP from POP3 server without imap package

Tags: php, email, pop3

I can't install the imap package of PHP in the machine so I need other type of library or some to **read** emails from a POP3 server (e.g.: Gmail).

Thanks!

Comment: You could try https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/ but Im not sure if this is possible without the imap lib. Alternatively you could look at a 3rd party like Mailgun who provide you an API that you can use to send emails.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but PHPMailer is only for sending, I need read emails from server.

Comment: In that case it will be unlikely you will find what you are looking for without the imap library. I would recommend looking for a 3rd party that will allow you to read the mailboxes using HTTP requests. I can't think of any but you might be able to find some on Google. Other than that perhaps you could chat to whom ever setup your server and see if they can compile PHP with imap. If you could get this setup on your server it would make everything far easier. I did have a quick look on Google checkout https://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=1469&lngWId=8

Comment: Thanks mic, I'll try with a class that uses sockets and telnet service to get the inbox. I returned to the 90's with this haha but I haven't another option.

Comment: No problem I hope you get it sorted. :)

Comment: maybe interesting? [Eden's POP3 object does uses fsocket() rather than PHP's built in IMAP functions for POP3.](https://github.com/Eden-PHP/Mail#pop3). You can setup 'gmail' to access it via `POP3` see: [How to Access a Gmail Account with any Email Client via POP](http://email.about.com/od/accessinggmail/qt/How_to_Access_a_Gmail_Account_with_any_Email_Client_via_POP.htm)

Comment: I came across this recently: [http://www.phpclasses.org/blog/package/2/post/1-Process-incoming-email-messages-using-PHP.html](http://www.phpclasses.org/blog/package/2/post/1-Process-incoming-email-messages-using-PHP.html). It claims to use POP3 without the need for the IMAP-extension.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I used a library that opens a socket and works through this sending commands and receiving lists of messages. The commands are the same that you can use to receive/send mails with telnet.

I hope this response can help someone.

Comment: This would help if you provide at least a name of a library you used :)

Comment: The library he is talking about is Eden, https://github.com/Eden-PHP/Mail Came to know about it by reading the comments in his question. For someone still finding the answer here :)